# what is the absolute address for data segment variable in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, real-mode

```
.data

len dw 10
msg db "1234567890"

.code
....
```

Address for segments
DS= 0ACA
CS =0AC7

What is the absolute address for string msg?

What I understand is effective address for msg is 21 in dec which 15H, then I do DS:0015 which is
ACB5 but it's not working..

The answers available are:

```
0ACA2

0ACC0

0ACC

0ACA0
```

Comment: Dude, stop posting your homework questions here.  Nobody is going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

Given your curent assumptions, you are making a sound calculation for the linear address.

`(0ACAh << 4) + 0015h` does indeed produce the linear address 0000ACB5h.

However, **why do you understand that the *msg* label is at offset 21 (15h)?**

Making the acceptable assumption that the `DS` segment register is pointing at the `.data` section and seeing next code snippet

```
.data
len dw 10
msg db "1234567890"
```

where the *len* variable occupies 2 bytes because that is what `dw` (DefineWord) does, the offset to *msg* will rather be **2**.

If you redo your calculation, you'll see that the correct answer in on the provided  list...